# wrong redirection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm experiencing a really weird behavior in my Rails app. I have a nested resource *Sensor* and in its controller I have an action to import records from a csv file. The end of that action is:

```
redirect_to deployment_sensors_path 
#venue_sensors_path's value is '/deployments/38/sensors' which looks good
```

The problem is that the redirection goes to a wrong action 'location' in the same controller. With no output in the console showing a change in the redirection. I don't have any before_filters in that controller and my routes.rb looks like:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :deployments do
  resources :sensors do
    collection do
      get 'location'
    end
  end
end
```

**Extras:**

This weird behavior happens no matter what path is in the redirect_to.

If I change the action name from 'location' to anything else everything works just fine.

Writing deployment_sensors_path directly in the browser address bar works perfectly.

I'm using Rails 4.

**Question:**

It seems location is a reserved word for a [render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) option to set the HTTP header. Could that be the problem? If not, What else can I do to debug this problem?